Нехватает прав на учётной записи группы "Администраторы"
Windows 11 одна единственная учётная запись Alen4ik у которой в дефолте группа прав Администраторы
Но одному приложению которое установлено и запускается с правами администратора - нехватает каких то ещё прав для корректной работы.
Но удивительно, что включив скрытую, встроенную в Windows учётную запись Администратор и попробов запустить приложение из под неё, приложению достаточно прав и оно корректно работает.
Есть ли какие либо мысли куда копать ?

UAC тоже на минимуме

Права папки во вкладке безопасность все открыты.



Но одному приложению которое установлено и запускается с правами администратора - нехватает каких то ещё прав для корректной работы. Каких именно прав нехватает? какие ошибки возникают, и что пишется в журналы?  А если исполняемый файл приложения запустить под текущей учёткой, но по правому клику с выбором пункта "Запуск от имени Администратора" - тогда прав достаточно?

@Akina запускал и с ПКМ - "Запуск от имени администратора" - всё равно некорректно работает. Не может вносить изменение в папке / файле. Где посмотреть журнал ?

@Akina проблема имено в правах... Так как на скрытой встроенной учётке Администратор всё работает прекрасно. А на учётной записи Alen4ik администратор - не работает)

Где посмотреть журнал ? Системные журналы Windows, апплет Просмотр событий. Скорее всего журнал Приложение, но посмотри также Безопасность и Система. Не может вносить изменение в папке / файле. Проверяй права в ФС. См. эффективные права и на папку, и на отдельные файлы.

@Akina сбой модуля происходит.
